# Can I modify the Icon in a Salesforce1 Custom Button accessed Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, custom-button, tab, quote

I have a requirement where a user needs to be able to access a Quote object in Salesforce1, and then navigate to a related Visualforce page for the Quote while still in Salesforce1 on their mobile device.

I am aware for most objects, navigating to a related VF page for an object is possible through a publisher action, but publisher actions are not available for Quotes (please vote up this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l8HQAAY)

I have worked around this by adding a custom detail page button that links to the Visualforce page, enabling the page for mobile, and adding the button to the page layout. Works ok, it appears in the publisher actions. However, I cannot see how to change the Icon from this basic spanner. I have several actions I want to add in a similar vein, and it will be very confusing to the User to see the same icon for every action. Any ideas???

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach, I think you can change the icon for each object (in this case, Quote?) from Customize -> Action -> Change Icon Does that not work for Quotes?

Comment: This is not a publisher action (as mentioned above), so I cannot change the icon using the buttons and links menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue and haven't seen any solutions. The work around would be to create a custom action just for Salesforce1, perhaps replicating the action of the button with JavaScript that redirects the user to the Visualforce page.

I've just submitted an idea to Salesforce for this fix if you'd like to vote for it:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DoTIAA0

Until then I'll likely need to replicate buttons with actions. With Summer '15, it looks like there's a new option on the page layout that allows you to override which actions/buttons are shown on Salesforce1 vs the desktop so we won't have to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the icon can be changed .for this  you need to first add the icon in static resource and then come back to the button and can change the icon by choosing the icon stored in static resource